# GridView not changing to edit mode when EditIndex is set on RowEditing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, edit

I am using Visual Studio 2010, VB.NET, target framework .NET 4.0.

I have a GridView which I am binding to some object collection, with a CommandField column that should allow edit of the selected row.

I am setting the EditIndex property correctly in the RowEditing eventhandler.

The problem is: When I click the "Edit" link that is generated, nothing apparently happens, the row gets rendered again in "view mode", not "edit mode".

But if I do some random postback, like clicking my "doNothing" button, the row gets rendered in "edit mode" in the next postback.

I have managed to reproduce the problem in the following code:

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MyForm.aspx.vb" Inherits="MySandBox.MyForm" %>

<%@ Register Src="MyControl.ascx" TagName="MyControl" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvInfrator" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MyField" DataField="MyField" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnDoNothing" runat="server" Text="Just do a postback" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
Public Class MyDto
    Public Property MyField As String
End Class

Public Class MyForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.BindMyData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindMyData()
        Dim myData As New MyDto
        myData.MyField = "My field value"

        Me.gvInfrator.DataSource = New MyDto() {myData}
        Me.gvInfrator.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvInfrator_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gvInfrator.RowEditing
        Me.BindMyData() 

        Me.gvInfrator.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    End Sub

End Class
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in .NET Framework 4? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Bind your data _after_ you set the `EditIndex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind your data *after* you set the `EditIndex` of your GridView.

```
Protected Sub gvInfrator_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gvInfrator.RowEditing
    Me.gvInfrator.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    Me.BindMyData() 
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem! Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to write a good, thorough question.